# How to rebuild when modifying JavaScript /resources file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vite

I'm new to programming. Recently, I've been working on developing a website using the Laravel Framework. I've noticed that whenever I make changes to the JavaScript files in the /resources folder, I have to run `npm run build` to see the updates on the website. After some research, I came across Vite. However, even when I use `npm run dev` and make changes to my JavaScript files, the updates don't take effect. Does anyone have any ideas on how to solve this issue? Thank you.

This is my vite config :

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel, { refreshPaths } from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

import fs from 'fs-extra';
import path from 'path';

const folder = {
    src: "resources/", // source files
    src_assets: "resources/", // source assets files
    dist: "public/", // build files
    dist_assets: "public/build/" //build assets files
};

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        manifest: true,
        rtl: true,
        outDir: 'public/build/',
        cssCodeSplit: true,
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                assetFileNames: (css) => {
                    if (css.name.split('.').pop() == 'css') {
                        return 'css/' + `[name]` + '.min.' + 'css';
                    } else {
                        return 'icons/' + css.name;
                    }
                },
                entryFileNames: 'js/' + `[name]` + `.js`,
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel(
            {
                input: [
                    'resources/scss/bootstrap.scss',
                    'resources/scss/icons.scss',
                    'resources/scss/app.scss',
                    'resources/scss/custom.scss',
                ],
                refresh: [
                    ...refreshPaths,
                    'resources/views/**',
                ],
            }
        ),
        {
            name: 'copy-specific-packages',
            async writeBundle() {

                try {
                    // Copy images, json, fonts, and js
                    await Promise.all([
                        fs.copy(folder.src_assets + 'fonts', folder.dist_assets + 'fonts'),
                        fs.copy(folder.src_assets + 'images', folder.dist_assets + 'images'),
                        fs.copy(folder.src_assets + 'js', folder.dist_assets + 'js'),
                        fs.copy(folder.src_assets + 'json', folder.dist_assets + 'json'),
                    ]);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error copying assets:', error);
                }

                const outputPath = path.resolve(__dirname, folder.dist_assets); // Adjust the destination path
                const configPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'package-copy-config.json');

                try {
                    const configContent = await fs.readFile(configPath, 'utf-8');
                    const { packagesToCopy } = JSON.parse(configContent);

                    for (const packageName of packagesToCopy) {
                        const destPackagePath = path.join(outputPath, 'libs', packageName);

                        const sourcePath = (fs.existsSync(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', packageName + "/dist"))) ?
                            path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', packageName + "/dist")
                            : path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', packageName);

                        try {
                            await fs.access(sourcePath, fs.constants.F_OK);
                            await fs.copy(sourcePath, destPackagePath);
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.error(`Package ${packageName} does not exist.`);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error copying and renaming packages:', error);
                }
            },
        },

    ],
});
```

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "name": "cfm",
    "version": "1.0",
    "type": "module",
    "author": "test",
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "rimraf public/build",
        "dev": "vite dev",
        "build": "npm run clean && vite build",
        "build-rtl": "rtlcss public/build/css/app.min.css & rtlcss public/build/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
        "axios": "^1.6.5",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^1.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.3.5",
        "postcss-import": "^14.0.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "rimraf": "^5.0.1",
        "rtlcss": "^3.0.0",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
        "vite": "^5.0.12"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^38.0.1",
        "@simonwep/pickr": "^1.8.2",
        "@tarekraafat/autocomplete.js": "^10.2.7",
        "aos": "^2.3.4",
        "apexcharts": "^3.41.0",
        "bootstrap": "5.3.2",
        "card": "^2.5.4",
        "chart.js": "4.3.0",
        "choices.js": "^10.2.0",
        "cleave.js": "^1.6.0",
        "dom-autoscroller": "^2.3.4",
        "dragula": "^3.7.3",
        "dropzone": "^6.0.0-beta.2",
        "echarts": "^5.4.2",
        "feather-icons": "^4.29.0",
        "fg-emoji-picker": "^1.0.1",
        "filepond": "^4.30.4",
        "filepond-plugin-file-encode": "^2.1.10",
        "filepond-plugin-file-validate-size": "^2.2.8",
        "filepond-plugin-image-exif-orientation": "^1.0.11",
        "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "^4.6.11",
        "flatpickr": "^4.6.13",
        "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
        "fs-extra": "^11.2.0",
        "fullcalendar": "^6.1.8",
        "glightbox": "^3.2.0",
        "gmaps": "^0.4.25",
        "gridjs": "^6.0.6",
        "isotope-layout": "^3.0.6",
        "jsvectormap": "1.4.2",
        "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
        "list.js": "^2.3.1",
        "list.pagination.js": "^0.1.1",
        "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2",
        "moment": "^2.30.1",
        "multi.js": "^0.5.3",
        "node-waves": "^0.7.6",
        "nouislider": "^15.7.0",
        "particles.js": "^2.0.0",
        "prismjs": "^1.29.0",
        "quill": "^1.3.7",
        "rater-js": "^1.0.1",
        "sass": "^1.69.5",
        "shepherd.js": "^11.1.1",
        "simplebar": "^6.2.5",
        "sortablejs": "^1.15.0",
        "sweetalert2": "^11.6.13",
        "swiper": "^9.3.2",
        "toastify-js": "^1.12.0",
        "wnumb": "^1.2.0"
    }
}
```

This is my folder structure:
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU4b8.png)

Comment: Just add this flag in package.json `"dev": "vite dev --watch",`

Comment: @502_Geek it showed this after i paste `vite dev -- watch`  `CACError: Unknown option `--watch``

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are using Laravel version 10.
In version 10, as far as I know, `npm run dev` is only used if you use Laravel Mix. In version 10, Laravel Mix started migrating to Vite.

So, when you want to compile assets in Laravel 10, use `npm run build`, then your assets will be updated in the `public/build` folder. Don't forget to use `{{ URL::asset('build/images/favicon.ico') }}` in every meta tag related to scripts, images, and links

For more info about Laravel Mix Migration see:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mix

### UPDATE ANSWER

Or :

add

```
"dev": "vite dev",
"build": "vite build",
"watch": "vite build --watch",
```

on you package.json then execute

> npm run watch

See the documentation:
https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#rebuild-on-files-changes

Comment: Means I'm force to always npm run build to see changes in my js script ? thats crazy

Comment: after i add `"watch": "vite build --watch"` and `npm run watch` it will automatically build the first time, but after i modify anything inside the resources folder it wont reload the build. its the same

Comment: There is no other way, install Laravel Mix manually